# Get URL in Windows 8 using WinJs.xhr rss feed into iframe

Tags: javascript, html, windows, windows-8, rss

So i'm developing a program in windows 8, and my goal is to get an rss feed, which works. however when clicked I would like it to display an iframe of the url. Here is the javascript code I have:

```
function GetRss() {
        WinJS.xhr({ url: "http://URL.com/rss", responseType: 'responseXML' }).then(function (rss) {
           var items = rss.responseXML.querySelectorAll("item");

           for (var n = 0; n < items.length; n++) {
               var article = {};
               article.title = items[n].querySelector("title").textContent;
               var imageStart = items[n].textContent.indexOf('<img src="') + 11;
               var imageEnd = items[n].textContent.indexOf('"', imageStart);
               article.thumbnail = items[n].textContent.substring(imageStart, imageEnd);
               articlesList.push(article);
               article.content = items[n].querySelector("link");
            }
        });

    }
```

and my html is:

```
            <div id="articlecontent"></div>
```

Thanks.

Comment: What specificially isn't working? What is your problem? Is creating an iframe, and setting it's src property to the URL not working?

Comment: Currently this just displays the link. I want to add an iframe before the link, so the src of the iframe would be the feed URL. Also it doesn't work when putting it in the body.

Comment: I still don't understand -- you have an iframe, and you set it's .src property (e.g. `var iframe = getIFrameSomeWhere(); iframe.src = article.content`), and it's displaying the LINK and not the CONTENT?

Comment: Sorry, disregard that previous comment. When I try creating the iframe then setting its src property to the url, it says the id is undefined.

Comment: Can you share your code where you actually set the SRC.

Comment: This is how I'm trying to call the url:                       `article.link = items[n].querySelector("url").textContent;
               var req = "<iframe id='ifrd'></iframe>";
               var iframe = ifrd(); iframe.src = article.link;

               article.content = req;`